# fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gtkmm

## i couldn't figureout what's wrong in this code

## whatever edit i do, it gives same error every time

```
all : asio - 1.12.2 src / chat_server client

asio - 1.12.2 :
     tar xzf asio - 1.12.2.tar.gz

client : src / client.cpp src / mainwin.cpp src/*.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) src/client.cpp src/mainwin.cpp $(GTKFLAGS) -o src/client

GTKLINKFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0)
GTKCOMPILEFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0)


CXXFLAGS+= -DASIO_STANDALONE -Wall -O0 -g -std=c++11
CPPFLAGS+=-I./include -I./asio-1.12.2/include -I./src ${GTKCOMPILEFLAGS}
LDLIBS+= -lpthread ${GTKLINKFLAGS}

clean:
    -rm -rf asio-1.12.2
    -rm -f src/client
    -rm -f src/chat_server
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error. In:

```
client : src / client.cpp src / mainwin.cpp src/*.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) src/client.cpp src/mainwin.cpp $(GTKFLAGS) -o src/client
```

You are using `$(GTKFLAGS)` which is empty. To notice it type: `make -n`. In your case replace it by `$(GTKCOMPILEFLAGS) $(GTKLINKFLAGS)` but this is not a nice fix because you should separate your Makefile rules:

- one for compiling each cpp file into object file (.o)
- and one rule for linking all objects files into your binary.