# Compiling error: "fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors

I have never gotten much further than creating a hello world program, so forgive my lack of knowledge.

I run into this issue when I try to compile my code:

```cpp
#include "gtkmm.h"

class MyWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MyWindow();
};
    
MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    set_title("Basic application");
    set_default_size(200, 200);
}
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.examples.base");
    return app->make_window_and_run<MyWindow>(argc, argv);
}
```

The issue:

```
[me@fedora build]$ cmake --build .
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/me/Documents/Programs/Testing/hello_world/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "gtkmm.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
[me@fedora build]$
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(hello_world)

add_executable(app main.cpp)
```

Comment: you need to edit your makefile to tell it where your library files are located

Comment: Your CMakeLists.txt does not find or use gtkmm Related: [https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/UsingCMake](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/UsingCMake)

Comment: Related/dupe: [fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311381/)